# Setting default raster statistics extent in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology

I recently found the setting in QGIS to rescale raster symbology using the current extent, which is really handy (Layer styling > Min/Max Value Settings).

[image: Layer styling options]

My question is - can the default extent be changed? At the moment, when you add a new raster to the map, the statistics extent is set to Whole raster. I would like the default to be Current canvas.

Comment: IMO it does not exist a possibility to set it to default yet. If you have a look to the advanced settings editor, you can set the count cut, the default standart derivation, but no statistic extent. If you save your raster style to default, you will save also the statistic extent setting to the style, that is one possibility, but with every new layer you will have the same. Other possibility: make a feature request on: https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues